# How to make only own child visible on hover, using only css

Tags: html, css

I am working with a list of items, and when each item is hovered, I need to show an element inside that item.
Is there a way to achieve this using only css?

> Update: Using direct descendent operator `(>)` is a solution, but element to show/hide may be deeper down

HTML

```
<div class="list-of-things">
  <div class="each-item">
    ...
    // deeper down in the tree
    <div class="invisible-element">
      Show me only when *my* parent is hovered
    </div>
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="each-item">
    ...
    // deeper down in the tree
    <div class="invisible-element">
      Show me only when *my* parent is hovered
    </div>
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.each-item:hover {
  // ???
  // (only-this) .invisible-element {
  //   visibility: visible;
  // }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Be careful that `visibility:hidden` is different from `display:none`, while both different than a 3rd possibility to hide an element, namingly  `opacity:0`. More than often you'll probably use `display` rather than the 2 others. [Here's an article](https://thisthat.dev/display-none-vs-opacity-0-vs-visibility-hidden/) about that.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
#parent .hidden-child{
    visibility: hidden;
}

#parent:hover .hidden-child{
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: This would work, except adding `#id` based individual css entry for each item in the list does not seem practical...

Answer (score 1):

Use the `>` css selector. In your case it would be:

> element > element
>
> `div > p`
>
> Selects all `p` elements where the parent is a `div` element

```css
.invisible-element {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.each-item:hover > .invisible-element {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="list-of-things">
  <div class="each-item">
    <div class="invisible-element">
      Show me only when *my* parent is hovered
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="each-item">
    <div class="invisible-element">
      Show me only when *my* parent is hovered
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes this would work, but the elements mights be deeper down, in which case, we end up with `div > div > div ...`. Is there another way, without using direct descendent operator? Thanks.